# how to use a variable inside json object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const DenseTable=({x,y,table})=> {
 
    return(
      <><tbody>
                  {table.map((item)=>
                    <tr style={{backgroundColor:" #f3f6f9"}}>
                        <td>P{item.priority}</td>
                        <td>{item.Artificial}</td>
                        <td>{item.Natural}</td>
                    </tr>
                    )}
              </tbody> 
    </> 
    </tbody>
```

instead of item.Artificial, I need to use item.x (x being the prop). what should be the syntax?

Comment: Could you show the structure of your JSON object?

Comment: You can access like `item[x]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a variable you need to write that variable inside big bracket.

```
const DenseTable=({x,y,table})=> {

return(
  <><tbody>
              {table.map((item)=>
                <tr style={{backgroundColor:" #f3f6f9"}}>
                    <td>P{item.priority}</td>
                    <td>{item[x]}</td>
                    <td>{item.Natural}</td>
                </tr>
                )}
          </tbody> 
</> 
</tbody>
```